# batch script how to create an array with specific continued numbers

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to create an integer array that stops at a limit number and then goes on after another fixed value. Something like [1 2 3 4 5 10 11 12 13 14 15 16], where 5 is the limit number and 10 where it restarts.
Can you do something like `set arr = [1:%lim%, 10:%max%]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

CALL :buildlist mylist 1 5 10 16

ECHO list is %mylist%

PAUSE

GOTO :eof

:: Produce a list of integers
:: %1 is listname
:: %2 is start value
:: %3 is end-value for range
:: %4 is restart-value
:: %5 is end-value

:buildlist
SET "%1="
FOR /L %%v IN (%2,1,%5) DO (
 IF %%v leq %3 CALL SET "%1=%%%1%% %%v" 
 IF %%v geq %4 CALL SET "%1=%%%1%% %%v"
)

CALL SET "%1=%%%1:~1%%"

GOTO :eof
```

Batch really doesn't have arrays, but can simulate one with a little imagination.

The above routine produces a list of values to the specification, ready for processing by a `for` statement.

Although it's possible to use `delayedexpansion`, it's possible to avoid that facility. By `CALL` ing a `set` command, the command is parsed before execution so to decode the hieroglyphics, where `%1` is the variable name "var"

```
SET "%1=%%%1%% %%v"
```

is processed as:

```
SET "var=%var% %v"
```

as `%%` is an escaped-%, and `%v` will be replaced by the value of the metavariable (loop-control variable) `%%v`

Similarly,

```
SET "%1=%%%1:~1%%"
```

is executed as

```
SET "var=%var:~1%"
```

which deletes the first character, which will be a space.

Comment: the funny thing is I already have a code with two loops for each set and I was trying to simplify it by putting everything in one set

Comment: Actually in your expansion explanation, `%%v` would also become processed as `%v`, because the `%`-escaping by doubling them is the actual reason for why they also have to be doubled at `for` meta-variables in batch files, and `for` itself only receives a singe `%`…

Comment: @aschipfl : quite so. I think I've fixed it - the issue is whether I've used the symbols in their original or sub-shell context.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is about *several* `for /L` commands really, although it could be described in terms of nested `if` commands or in other different ways...

There are several different methods to give the values of the `for` commands, and also to implement they. I think this is the simplest one:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set ranges="1:5" "10:16"

set "list="
for %%a in (%ranges::= 1 %) do for /L %%i in (%%~a) do set "list=!list! %%i"

echo list=%list%
```

Note that this method also works with *several* (more than two) ranges of values.

PS - This result is a *list*, not an [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Comment: Can you tell me in short what `%ranges::= 1 %` and `%%~a` do here ? I understand you set the limits in ranges and then "fill" them in the second loop, but i dont understand the syntax

Comment: @alfred: `%ranges::= 1 %` changes the colon by space-1-space, so it generates `"1 1 5" "10 1 16"`. In the first `for %%a` each _string in quotes_ is assigned to `%%a`. Then, `%%~a` is the same string without the quotes, so it first completes `for /L %%i in (1 1 5) do ...` and then `for /L %%i in (10 1 16) do ...`. In `for /L` command you can separate the 3 values by comma, semicolon, equal-sign or space.

Comment: Ok got it, that's nice

Answer (score 1):

Batch doesn't have `OR` operators, so you'll have to make do with two separate `if` statements - one for the first set of numbers and one for the second set of numbers. You can, however, put both of those in the same `for` loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "lim=5"
set "max=10"

REM Setting counter to -1 because we're going to increment the counter and then
REM use it, and arrays famously start at zero.
set "counter=-1"
for /L %%A in (1,1,16) do (
    if %%A LEQ %lim% (
        set /a counter+=1
        set "array[!counter!]=%%A"
    )
    if %%A GEQ %max% (
        set /a counter+=1
        set "array[!counter!]=%%A"
    )
)

REM Display the contents of the array just to prove it worked.
REM Alphabetic order is used, so array[10] and array[11] are going to print before array[1]
set array[
```